# How to get StackExchange user's email ID through the API

Tags: stackexchange-api

Is there any way I can retrieve the user's registered email ID through the stack exchange API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intentionally can *not* get this information. Stack Exchange [removed that information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221032/186281) from the quarterly-ish data dump as well.

The choice to keep this inaccessible is to protect users' privacy.